# How can I fix this type mismatch error when calling JS from VBScript?

Tags: javascript, vbscript

In the onclick event of an HTML button, I call this sub:

```
Sub SaveStuff(SQLQuery, DOMFieldID, ButtonId, ButtonColour)
    dbConn.Execute SQLQuery
    Call resetButtonColors(DOMFieldID)
    Call changeButtonColor(ButtonId, ButtonColour)
End Sub
```

resetButtonColors and changeButtonColor are JS functions.

```js
function resetButtonColors(groupName){
    var elements = document.getElementsByName(groupName)
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
    {
        elements[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(192,192,192)"
    }
}

function changeButtonColor(btn, newColor){
    var element = document.getElementById(btn);
    element.style.backgroundColor = newColor 
}
```

But I am getting a type mismatch error that I don't know how to fix. I tried to cast the values to string but didn't work.

Comment: On which line are you getting the error? And please show how you are calling the sub and the related html.

Comment: I would start by establishing that what is being passed in is correct, use an `alert()` in the JS functions to see if `groupName`, `btn` and `newColor` are being passed and are the correct type. This is basic debugging which you should be doing with these types of issues before you even ask here. In fact `Type Mismatch` errors are VBScript runtime errors so you want to check the `SaveStuff()` sub procedure to see what it is passing `SQLQuery`, `DOMFieldID`, `ButtonId` and `ButtonColour`, you can use `MsgBox()` function to do that.